# RecylerView not recycling background color

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view which works fine except that it does not recycler the background color of the rows. Here is the relevant code from the adapter:

```
 override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    holder.apply {

        if (years.size > 1 && position % 2 == 0 ) {
            rowBackground.setBackgroundColor(ColorUtils.setAlphaComponent(utils.getThemeColor(), 20))
        }else {
            rowBackground.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
        }

      
    }
}



class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    val rowBackground: LinearLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.history_row_background)
}
```

Here is how it looks:

[image]

Everything else gets recycled but not the background color. What am I doing wrong?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Most likely to be the `if conditions` have you tried with out it

Comment: @AnaniyaJemberu I want to change the color for every other row. I've added an image to show how it currently looks.

Comment: Why do you have the condition `years.size > 1` ?

Comment: The code looks OK. Are you sure that `onBindViewHolder()` is being called when you expect? Use logcat to check that out. Also, are the items being shifted around at all? You may not get a call to  `onBindViewHolder()` if _RecyclerView_ determines that nothing has changed for the position. See the [note](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#onBindViewHolder(VH,%20int)) for the method.

Comment: Use position % 2 == 1 instead of position % 2 == 0 it works for me.